# $match(aggregation) cannot compare two object ids

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I want to perform a join using the $lookup operation.

My objects contain 2D coordinates field, and the collection is indexed with this field.

I want to find Object **pairs**.

Thus I first extract objects lying within a small space region and push this selection into a 'z' collection:

```
p1 = [
    {'$geoNear':
        {
            'near': [0, 0],
            'query': { 'loc': { '$geoWithin': {'$box': [bottomleft, topright] } } },
            'distanceField': 'dist',
        }
    },
    {'$out': 'z'},
]
```

Then I join this 'z' selection with the same selection from the original collection:

```
p2 = [
    {'$geoNear':
        {
            'near': [0, 0],
            'query': { 'loc': { '$geoWithin': {'$box': [bottomleft, topright] }  } },
            'distanceField': 'dist',
        }
    },
    {'$lookup': {'from':'z', 'localField':'y.loc', 'foreignField':'z.loc', 'as':'ns'} },
    {'$unwind': '$ns'},
    {'$match': {'_id': {'$ne': '$ns._id'}}},
]
```

And using this '$match' above, I'd like to reject the pairs involving one object with itself:

```
{'$match': {'_id': {'$ne': '$ns._id'}}},
```

But this does not work:

```
0 {'_id': ObjectId('5908e654d15fa1043596a382'), 'dist': 0.0, 'ns': {'_id': ObjectId('5908e654d15fa1043596a382')}}
1 {'_id': ObjectId('5908e654d15fa1043596a382'), 'dist': 0.06338084493056388, 'ns': {'_id': ObjectId('5908e674d15fa10435cc739e')}}
2 {'_id': ObjectId('5908e654d15fa1043596a382'), 'dist': 0.227329384268223, 'ns': {'_id': ObjectId('5908e65fd15fa10435ab436e')}}
3 {'_id': ObjectId('5908e654d15fa1043596a382'), 'dist': 0.23787682552971529, 'ns': {'_id': ObjectId('5908e64cd15fa1043585a065')}}
```

Obviously, the match did not operate since the pair #0 is a pair of one object to itself.

How to write the $match operation ?? It seems that the '$ne' operator would not apply for object ids????

Thanks
Christian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace your `$match` with `$redact`.

`$redact` will compare `$_id` & `$ns._id` and will `$$PRUNE` matching ids and `$$KEEP` non matching ids.

```
{
    $redact: {
        $cond: [{
                $eq: ["$_id", "$ns._id"]
            },
            "$$PRUNE",
            "$$KEEP"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this suggestion... I'll try it

Comment: ... and of course i'll let you know if it worked ;-) . Christian

Comment: OK: what you proposed works just fine. Thanks again. I close. Christian